# Export MODIS MOD16A2 data from a graph in GEE to a CSV file directly on the google Drive

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, modis, time-series

How can I export the average MODIS AET values for an ensemble of points defined by a shapefile, obtained as a graph using GEE, directly to my Google Drive in CSV format? I have attempted to use the "Export.table.toDrive" command but have been unsuccessful.

The GEE script I'm using:

```
var modisPET= ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MOD16A2");
var collection05=ee.ImageCollection(modisPET.filterDate('2000-02-01', '2021-12-31'));


print(collection05, 'collection05')

var listMillis = ee.List(collection05.aggregate_array('system:time_start'));
var uniqueDates = listMillis.distinct();

collection05 = collection05.map(function(image){
  return image.set('simpleDateMillis', ee.Date(image.date().format('YYYY-MM')).millis())
});
var listMillisSimple = ee.List(collection05.aggregate_array('simpleDateMillis'));
var uniqueDatesSimple = listMillisSimple .distinct();
print(collection05)

print(uniqueDatesSimple, 'unique year month combinations')

var monthlyMean = uniqueDatesSimple.map(function(date){
  
  var monthStart = ee.Date(date)
  var monthEnd = ee.Date(date).advance(1, 'month').advance(-1,'day')
  
  var subset = collection05.filterDate(monthStart,monthEnd);
  
  
  return ee.Image(subset.mean()).copyProperties(subset.first());
});

print(monthlyMean, 'monthlyMean')
var printMonthly = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(monthlyMean, point,ee.Reducer.mean(), 'ET',1000, 'simpleDateMillis')
print(printMonthly, 'printMonthly')
```